# Ace editor - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientX' of undefined

Tags: mootools, ace-editor

Im using ace editor and mootools.
I have just updated my mootools to version 1.4.5 and when i click/drag on the editor i get js exception:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientX' of undefined
```

Please help... Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Instead of removing the bind method always I think I found a workaround. It seems that only a couple of Mootools builds have this issue. So I use this code to fix them:

```
if (this.MooTools.build=='ab8ea8824dc3b24b6666867a2c4ed58ebb762cf0') {
    delete Function.prototype.bind;

    Function.implement({

        /*<!ES5-bind>*/
        bind: function(that){
            var self = this,
                args = arguments.length > 1 ? Array.slice(arguments, 1) : null,
                F = function(){};

            var bound = function(){
                var context = that, length = arguments.length;
                if (this instanceof bound){
                    F.prototype = self.prototype;
                    context = new F;
                }
                var result = (!args && !length)
                    ? self.call(context)
                    : self.apply(context, args && length ? args.concat(Array.slice(arguments)) : args || arguments);
                return context == that ? result : context;
            };
            return bound;
        },
        /*</!ES5-bind>*/
    });
}
```

The benefit is that I can fix it for each build separately. The drawback is clearly to have mootools code shipped with my own code. But currently I see no other option and since I code for Joomla I'm pretty sure that there is a limited number of mootools versions in use.

Answer (score 1):

i solve it for my situation!
i've delete some lines from mootools.js:

1) bind:function(e){var a=this,b=arguments.length>1?Array.slice(arguments,1):null,d=function(){};var c=function(){var g=e,h=arguments.length;if(this instanceof c){d.prototype=a.prototype;
g=new d;}var f=(!b&&!h)?a.call(g):a.apply(g,b&&h?b.concat(Array.slice(arguments)):b||arguments);return g==e?f:g;};return c;}

2) delete Function.prototype.bind;

(i don't need mouse binding in mootools so it's revelation for me!)

Answer (score 0):

This is a very strange error. During debugging I didn't get the error. But as soon as I removed the breakpoint it appeared again. I finally solved the issue by [adding the latest version of mootools 1.4.5](http://mootools.net/core/ab8ea8824dc3b24b6666867a2c4ed58ebb762cf0) to joomla. The error was immediately gone.